# SSAS DAX Grand Total not matching with actual Sum

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular, daxstudio

I have a fact which has relationships with 2 dimension tables.

1. Direct relationship
2. Through Bridge table

[image]

I have created a sum measure that should sum up the Amount column.

I have created two queries that don't give me the expected result

**Query 1:**

```
Sum of Amount:= CALCULATE(SUM(Fact[Amount]))
```

**Current result** : The Grand total is 600

[image]

**Query 2:**

```
Sum of Amount:= IF(HASONEVALUE('Dimension 1'[value]),CALCULATE(SUM(Fact[Amount])),
SUMX(VALUES('Dimension 1'[value]),CALCULATE(SUM(Fact[Amount]))))
```

**Current result** : The Grand Total is 400

[image]

**Expected result** : When the Dimension 1 is selected, the grand total should be 400 and when the Dimension 2 selected the Grand total should be 600.

[image]

Could anyone please help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that it is not possible to have a measure that behaves differently on the totals when in the visual a different dimension is selected on the rows.

This happens because when evaluating the totals there is no filter on the dimension.

It would be like having a measure that can give two different results when no dimension is selected, for instance in a card visual.

SO answer is to implement two separate measures.

Otherwise to select the behavior using a slicer on a parameter table, or to use a calculation group.